# Where to draw line between a physics question and a meta physics?

Tags: discussion

- I will give two example to put forward my question.
  Hierarchy Problem now when I heard this question I found it a lot of metaphysical question because it asks why there is so much discrepancy between weak force and gravity.
- Mass generation problem this again ask for the reason why particles get their mass in first place.

Though physicists are working on these questions I am still skeptical about the idea of involvement of metaphysics in here. Also, I don't understand why metaphysics suffers so harsh criticism by physicists?

Comment: With questions that border on the metaphysical I feel like the reaction depends on *who* is asking in the sense that many physicists emphatically *don't* want to talk about that stuff with someone who is not an accomplished physicist themselves. Because people who've read a lot of pop-sci but not learned the real thing will generally not even be able to understand the criticism leveled against their ideas which makes the "discussion" pointless.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this meta site is (despite its name) not about [metaphysics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphysics) but _about Physics Stack Exchange or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network within the scope defined in the help center._